# How to create / integrate the Yelp Dataset in SQLite (Coursera SQL for Data Science)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, yelp

I am doing the **Coursera** course ***[SQL for Data Science](https://www.coursera.org/learn/sql-for-data-science)***. Logically I am a bloody beginner.

For the final assignment you have to analyze the **Yelp dataset**. However, there is no description on how to obtain the dataset, how to transform it, how to integrate it etc.

If I am downloading the dataset from here: https://www.yelp.com/dataset/download
, Which I think is the correct one, I receive a handful of *.json files.

**How would I create a SQLite database from this?** Or is there somewhere already an **SQLite-ready Yelp database to download**?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Surely this is a question your instructor could answer??

Comment: Did you read the documentation hosted on the same site?  It also provides links to example code hosted in github.  https://www.yelp.com/dataset/documentation/main

Comment: You were both right. It was hidden in plain sight. It was under reading material, which I normally read AFTER I finished the tests. Therefore, I just oversaw it. 
Thanks for taking the time to comment. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the dataset included in the Coursera material within the

> Week 4:  Reading:Yelp Dataset SQL Lookup (5min)

It is the last of the 4 sections in the *Peer Review Assignment* panel

Good luck with the assignment